# keras BLSTM for sequence labeling

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm relatively new to neural nets so please excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to adapt the keras BLSTM example [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_bidirectional_lstm.py). The example reads in texts and classifies them as 0 or 1. I want a BLSTM that does something very much like POS tagging, though extras like lemmatizing or other advanced features are not neccessary, I just want a basic model. My data is a list of sentences and each word is given a category 1-8. I want to train a BLSTM that can use this data to predict the category for each word in an unseen sentence.

e.g. input = ['The', 'dog', 'is', 'red'] gives output = [2, 4, 3, 7]

If the keras example is not the best route, I'm open to other suggestions.

I currently have this:

```
'''Train a Bidirectional LSTM.'''

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Input, merge
from prep_nn import prep_scan


np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility
max_features = 20000
batch_size = 16
maxlen = 18

print('Loading data...')
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = prep_scan(nb_words=max_features,
                                                 test_split=0.2)
print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'test sequences')

print("Pad sequences (samples x time)")
# type issues here? float/int?
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, value=0.)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, value=0.)  # pad with zeros

print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)

# need to pad y too, because more than 1 ouput value, not classification?
y_train = sequence.pad_sequences(np.array(y_train), value=0.)
y_test = sequence.pad_sequences(np.array(y_test), value=0.)

print('y_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:', X_test.shape)

# this is the placeholder tensor for the input sequences
sequence = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')

# this embedding layer will transform the sequences of integers
# into vectors of size 128
embedded = Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen)(sequence)

# apply forwards LSTM
forwards = LSTM(64)(embedded)
# apply backwards LSTM
backwards = LSTM(64, go_backwards=True)(embedded)

# concatenate the outputs of the 2 LSTMs
merged = merge([forwards, backwards], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
after_dp = Dropout(0.5)(merged)
# number after dense has to corresponse to output matrix?
output = Dense(17, activation='sigmoid')(after_dp)

model = Model(input=sequence, output=output)

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=4,
          validation_data=[X_test, y_test])

X_test_new = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,3,55,4,34,5,45,3,9],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7,65,34,67,34,23,24,67,54,43,]])

classes = model.predict(X_test_new, batch_size=16)
print(classes)
```

My output is the right dimension, but is giving me floats 0-1. I think this is because it's still looking for binary classfication. Anyone know how to fix this?

SOLVED

Just make sure the labels are each binary arrays:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), maxlen, word_ids, tags_ids = prep_model(
    nb_words=nb_words, test_len=75)

W = (y_train > 0).astype('float')

print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(int(len(X_train)*val_split), 'validation sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'heldout sequences')

# this is the placeholder tensor for the input sequences
sequence = Input(shape=(maxlen,), dtype='int32')

# this embedding layer will transform the sequences of integers
# into vectors of size 256
embedded = Embedding(nb_words, output_dim=hidden,
                     input_length=maxlen, mask_zero=True)(sequence)

# apply forwards LSTM
forwards = LSTM(output_dim=hidden, return_sequences=True)(embedded)
# apply backwards LSTM
backwards = LSTM(output_dim=hidden, return_sequences=True,
                 go_backwards=True)(embedded)

# concatenate the outputs of the 2 LSTMs
merged = merge([forwards, backwards], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
after_dp = Dropout(0.15)(merged)

# TimeDistributed for sequence
# change activation to sigmoid?
output = TimeDistributed(
    Dense(output_dim=nb_classes,
          activation='softmax'))(after_dp)

model = Model(input=sequence, output=output)

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
# loss=binary_crossentropy, optimizer=rmsprop
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam',
              sample_weight_mode='temporal')

print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=epochs,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_split=val_split,
          sample_weight=W)
```

Comment: Could you please upload a small sample of your data? It helps in better understanding how the model works. If it is not possible, could you please explain a little about how your raw data looks like and what you have done for data preprocessing before feeding the model?

Answer (score 4):

Solved. The main issue was reshaping the data for the classification categories as binary arrays. Also used TimeDistributed and set return_sequences to True.

Comment: Thanks! When we use `mask_zero=True` in the embedding layer, I guess all the following layers will ignore this class for computing the loss, accuracy etc.? And I guess the `nb_classes` in the output layer should be # of class + 1 (i.e., for binary classsification problem it's 3)? Thanks again!

Comment: yes, i believe that's correct (sorry it's been a while). This was the post that helped me a lot: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/957 . but there is still a masking issue for actually calculating the accuracy, and I don't think it's been fixed yet.

Comment: It's great that you answered your own question, but you should put you answer in your answer and not as an add-on to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I knows that this thread is very old but i hope will i can help.

I modified the model for a binary model:

```
sequence = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],), dtype='int32')

embedded = Embedding(max_fatures,embed_dim,input_length=X_train.shape[1], mask_zero=True)(sequence)

# apply forwards LSTM
forwards = LSTM(output_dim=hidden, return_sequences=True)(embedded)
# apply backwards LSTM
backwards = LSTM(output_dim=hidden, return_sequences=True,go_backwards=True)(embedded)

# concatenate the outputs of the 2 LSTMs
merged = concatenate([forwards, backwards])
after_dp = Dropout(0.15)(merged)
# add now layer LSTM without return_sequence
lstm_normal = LSTM(hidden)(merged)

# TimeDistributed for sequence
# change activation to sigmoid?
#output = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim=2,activation='sigmoid'))(after_dp)
#I changed output layer TimeDistributed for a Dense, for the problem of dimensionality and output_dim = 1 (output binary) 
output = Dense(output_dim=1,activation='sigmoid')(lstm_normal)

model = Model(input=sequence, output=output)

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
# loss=binary_crossentropy, optimizer=rmsprop
# I changed modelo compile by to binary and remove sample_weight_mode parameter
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam',
              )

print(model.summary())


###################################
#this is the line of training

model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=10,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_split=0.2,
          #sample_weight=W
         )

#In this moment work fine.....
Train on 536000 samples, validate on 134000 samples
Epoch 1/10
536000/536000 [==============================] - 1814s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4794 - acc: 0.7679 - val_loss: 0.4624 - val_acc: 0.7784
Epoch 2/10
536000/536000 [==============================] - 1829s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4502 - acc: 0.7857 - val_loss: 0.4551 - val_acc: 0.7837
Epoch 3/10
 99584/536000 [====>.........................] - ETA: 23:10 - loss: 0.4291 - acc: 0.7980
```